# flask render_template UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to render "static" HTML file in flask. I don't know how to display static HTML file with some polish  chars.

code :

```
@app.route("/file.html"  )  
def funct():
    return   render_template('file.html')
```

file.html:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% block content %}
XXXXXXXXXąćśółXXXXXXXX
{% endblock%}
```

error code:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 81: invalid start byte
```

Edit:

the only issue is related to chars : "ąćśół" (when deleted everything works fine)

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur ? You should post the full stack trace, it should point out the offending file and line number.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal working example with all imports to solve this question